# Center unordered list inside container div with fixed width list items?

Tags: css

How can I center the unordered list of items in the black container box? Depending on the size of the user's screen, an X amount of `li` items get shown per row. I want these items to always be centered within the black container. How can I do this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kw84kuw/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="gallery-wrap">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
margin: 100px auto 0;
max-width: 1060px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

#gallery-wrap {
background: #000;
clear: both;
outline: 1px solid #777;
padding: 30px 50px;
}

#gallery-wrap li {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to `#gallery-wrap` and reset `ul`'s `padding`.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/8kw84kuw/1/)**</kbd>

```css
#container {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  max-width: 1060px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
#gallery-wrap {
  background: #000;
  clear: both;
  outline: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#gallery-wrap li {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="gallery-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working fine in your fiddle. However, I can't get it to work on my site. Do you think you can help me out? The site is [here](http://hirespanoramiclandscapes.com/).

Comment: @J82 - It's not working because you are adding `float: left` to the `li`s. Remove the `float: left` from [here](http://s25.postimg.org/v5ar1ghan/here.png) and it will work.